# Lambda expression for foreach loops having child foreach loops(nested foreach) and change the value

Tags: c#, foreach, lambda, nested

I have two class like below:

```
    public class Notification
    {
        public System.Guid NotificationId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ClassId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> SentBy { get; set; }
        public string SenderName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Visible { get; set; }
        public string MessageText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ClassViewRegId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public List<MessageRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Recipient
    {
        public System.Guid NotificationRecipientId { get; set; }  
        public System.Guid NotificationId { get; set; }
        public string RecipientType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> RecipientId { get; set; }   
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ClassId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ClassViewRegId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now my code have List which have another list List.

So Im trying to check and change the value as below:

```
 notify.Where(n => n.Recipients.Where(r => r.RecipientType == "Teacher").ToList().ForEach(s=>s.RecipientType="");
```

Any one please help me how to check and change value of child list property.

Answer (score 3):

Use simple foreach loop:

```
var teachers = notify.SelectMany(n => n.Recipients)
                     .Where(r => r.RecipientType == "Teacher");

foreach(Recipient teacher in teachers)
    teacher.RecipientType = "";
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, and I need the same collection, just need to change the value only based on some condition.

Comment: @user3667751 thus teacher is a reference type, then all teachers inside notify objects will be updated